# Umbraco 7 403 pages for multi-language pages

Tags: c#, http, umbraco

With multi-language sites in umbraco, 404 pages can be set in umbracoSettings.config so that the content can be translated.

```
<errors>
  <error404>
  <errorPage culture="default">//yourDocumentType[@nodeName='404']</errorPage>
</error404>
```

Normally setting other error codes would be set in the Web.config that would redirect to a static .net page.

```
<customErrors mode=“On“ defaultRedirect=“Error.aspx“>           
  <error statusCode=“403“ redirect=“Error.aspx“ /> 
  <error statusCode=“404“ redirect=“Error.aspx“ />   
</customErrors>
```

Is there a way of being able to set HTTP status codes for other languages like you can with 404 error codes in umbracoSettings.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, as far as I know, this only works for 404 pages, I don't think you can use it to translate error pages for other status codes, sorry!

Comment: Cheers Tim. I always thought that it couldn't be done either, but worth asking.